# Mongo index question - same field repeated multiple times in a query

Tags: mongodb

I have a general question on how mongo db indexes work

Lets say I have an index on fieldA, fieldB, fieldC

Is the query

```
{fieldA : "A", fieldB: {"$gt" : 5},fieldB: {"$lt" : 10} , "fieldC" : "C}
```

same as

```
{fieldA : "A", fieldB: {"$gt" : 5,"$lt" : 10} , "fieldC" : "C}
```

when it comes to query performance?

Comment: Can you try to use [explain](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to check and compare the execution plan for the 2 queries?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your *general* question is "*yes, they are the same when it comes to performance*". But there's a big caveat here first when it comes to semantics and what query is actually communicated to the database from the driver.

To address the latter first, consider what happens when you paste the first query (plus the missing closing quotation mark) into the MongoDB shell (which runs javascript):

```
test> var query = {fieldA : "A", fieldB: {"$gt" : 5},fieldB: {"$lt" : 10} , "fieldC" : "C"}

test> query
{ fieldA: 'A', fieldB: { '$lt': 10 }, fieldC: 'C' }
```

Some programming languages (and therefore driver implementations) use data structures that do not support duplicate field names. In these situations the behavior you get is undefined and usually results in just one of the values getting captured as demonstrated above.

The documentation talks about that [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-field) and notes that such a query requires using the `$and` operator explicitly rather than relying on the implicit one. Therefore we can rewrite the first query as follows:

```
test> var query1 = {fieldA : "A", $and:[{fieldB: {"$gt" : 5}},{fieldB: {"$lt" : 10}}] , "fieldC" : "C"}

test> query1
{
  fieldA: 'A',
  '$and': [ { fieldB: { '$gt': 5 } }, { fieldB: { '$lt': 10 } } ],
  fieldC: 'C'
}
```

Now going back to the original main question, there should be no difference when it comes to performance. You can see this using @ray's suggestion to inspect `explain` output. Indeed the `queryPlanner.parsedQuery` should be the same between the two:

```
test> query1
{
  fieldA: 'A',
  '$and': [ { fieldB: { '$gt': 5 } }, { fieldB: { '$lt': 10 } } ],
  fieldC: 'C'
}
test> query2
{ fieldA: 'A', fieldB: { '$gt': 5, '$lt': 10 }, fieldC: 'C' }
test>

test> db.foo.find(query1).explain().queryPlanner.parsedQuery
{
  '$and': [
    { fieldA: { '$eq': 'A' } },
    { fieldC: { '$eq': 'C' } },
    { fieldB: { '$lt': 10 } },
    { fieldB: { '$gt': 5 } }
  ]
}
test> db.foo.find(query2).explain().queryPlanner.parsedQuery
{
  '$and': [
    { fieldA: { '$eq': 'A' } },
    { fieldC: { '$eq': 'C' } },
    { fieldB: { '$lt': 10 } },
    { fieldB: { '$gt': 5 } }
  ]
}
test>

test> JSON.stringify(db.foo.find(query1).explain().queryPlanner.parsedQuery) == JSON.stringify(db.foo.find(query2).explain().queryPlanner.parsedQuery)
true
```

Once the query has been parsed it will be planned the same way meaning that query performance should be the same.

In my personal opinion, the second query is much more readable so I would prefer that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was using MongoTemplate and was using the Java API. I was able to achieve the query but one issue was that the output of the query was 2 different fields.So i was curious about performance.

Comment: Because the parsedQuery is the same we can expect that performance will be the same. Let me know if there is anything else about your original question that I can help clarify